# Amazon app: how can I change the amazon country?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes, amazon

When I start the Amazon app on my M10 with Ubuntu-Touch this app starts automatically the UK store. I´m located in germany and would like to start the german store with this app.
When trying to change country at the bottom of Amazon app then the browser opens and starts my german store. The original Amazon app remains in UK settings and in the end this app doesn´t make sense for anyone except UK users.
Is there a way to exchange the web link below this app to directly connect to german store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Ubuntu touch store and search for amazon.de 
Then download, install and use that instead of the store that comes with the device.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Sorry for not trying the store by myself with amazon search

Comment: No problem. But can you please click the hook by the answer. With it you say, the answer is correct.